# kml not rendering on google map

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I am working on asp.net  mvc and I am trying to render my kml file on google map, my kml file in hosted on  example url http://111.11.11.00:1010/MAP_123.kml but when i am trying to render it on google map it's not rendering please suggest if am wrong

please check below code which I get from google map official documentation which i am using

```js
var src = 'http://111.11.11.00:1010/MAP_123.kml';

kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
  suppressInfoWindows: true,
  preserveViewport: true,
  map: mapp
});
```

Comment: Your URL http://111.11.11.00:1010/MAP_123.kml doesn't work (timeout).

Comment: sorry but this only for example

Comment: Ah yes, and how is anyone supposed to debug a non-existent KML file that's to be displayed on a non-existent map? Read [ask] and provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: you can download .kml from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J4qwjpZjSESLgtgw1X2_TuX8tbQN40ng/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Do this try and almost the map will be rendered

**Js Code :-**

```
  <script>
      var map;
      var src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/kml/westcampus.kml';

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
          suppressInfoWindows: true,
          preserveViewport: false,
          map: map
        });
        kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
          var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
          var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
          testimonial.innerHTML = content;
        });
      }
    </script>
```

**Load JS with You Map API Key :-**

```
<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion ,still not working I have kml  with size 3.36 MB but same kml is working on google earth